# A library in Java that can transform an HTML text into plain text?

Tags: java, html, plaintext

The problem is simple, I want to transform a HTML text to plain text, thinks like putting line-breaks where is the `<br>` or title tags, number or markers on lists, etc.

I'm using **BoilerPipe** at the moment to do this, but this is not the main target of this library. There is another one that can do this?

Comment: Good question, I've been using NekoHTML to get a DOM tree and then traverse all nodes, adding line breaks for `<p>`, `<br>` etc. Would be nice to find a well-tested library to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the java library for selenium. Use getBodyText() to get the plain body text with the html tags stripped out and properly formatted.

see...

[Selenium java API](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getBodyText%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a XML parser? That way, you have control over the spacing and line breaks.

I doubt a full-fledged HTML parser and formatter would be available, since that runs into issues such as CSS parsing and all that stuff.